# MATLAB program simulation with the given processor requirements

Tags: matlab, processor, execution-time

I have a system with configuration intel(R) core(TM) i3-5020U CPU @ 2.2 GHz,4GB RAM. But in order to compare the performance of my MATLAB program in terms of execution time, I need to execute it on a machine with configuration Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3570 CPU @ 3.40GHz, 16 GB RAM. Is there a way to perform this kind of simulation?

Answer (score 1):

**TL:DR:  No**.  Performance differences between Broadwell and IvyBridge depend on lots of complicated details.  (See [Agner Fog's microarch pdf for the low-level microarchitectural details](http://www.agner.org/optimize/), and also other stuff in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki)

It's likely that performance will scale with either clock speed or memory speed within maybe 10%, even between different microarchitectures, but it might not.

Using your own system, you can probably figure out how your code scales with CPU frequency, by forcing it to stay at minimum frequency for a test run.  If it's a lot less than perfect scaling, then memory speed is a big factor.  (The slower your CPU, the fewer cycles are spent waiting for memory.)

---

You can't extrapolate IvB i5 3.4GHz performance from BDW 2.2GHz performance without knowing a *lot* more details about *exactly* what your code bottlenecks on.  It's possible that it bottlenecks on the same simple thing on both CPUs, in which case you could extrapolate.  e.g. if it turns out that it bottlenecks on FP multiply latency, then run-time on IvB would be 5/3rds the run time on Broadwell (times the clock frequency ratio), since BDW has 3 cycle FP multiply and add, but SnB/IvB/Haswell have 5 cycle multiply.  (FMA is 5 cycles on BDW, if I recall correctly.  IvB doesn't support FMA, so if Matlab takes advantage of that on BDW, it's not even running the same machine code).

More likely, it's not that simple and cache / memory performance comes into it, too.  Haswell/Broadwell don't have L1 cache-bank conflicts, but SnB/IvB do.

Depending on how you run the workload on the i5 CPU, it might or might not be able to turbo up to higher than its rated 3.4GHz, further confounding any attempt to guess at performance.

Comment: It seems to be quite complicated. Anyways, thanks for the detailed description @Peter Cordes. Good Day.

Comment: @sai: yea exactly:  Theoretically possible, and interesting if you like microarchitecture details and performance analysis.  If you don't, then the answer is a simple "no".

Comment: @sai: I added some suggestions for getting a really rough estimate.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell with different computers to measure practical efficiency. That's why you usually use theoretical efficiency with **Big-O**, check the wiki page for [algorithm efficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_efficiency) and [Big-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) notation.

In the case you have access to both codes (yours, and the other guy's code), you can test them ***in the same computer*** with the [methods for measuring performance](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/measure-performance-of-your-program.html?requestedDomain=fr.mathworks.coml?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) proposed by mathworks, which are mainly time functions in real time and cpu time.

Lastly, you can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benchmark_(computing)#Challenges) several challenges about benchmarking that might be interesting to consider.

Comment: You need to run both codes on the same hardware for benchmarks to be meaningful, unless the difference is large.

Comment: @silgon Yea I have gone through those methods for measuring performance even before posting this question. I only have the results of the other guy's code but not the code itself. That's the problem here. Otherwise I would have checked the performance of both codes in a single system to get an idea over the performance. Thanks man!

Comment: @sai, you're welcome. It is an interesting question, mainly because in some scientific articles you find the time in which the algorithm runs in certain computer, so it could be difficult to compare with the state of the art. Good luck! =)